# Using only g++ works, but not "g++ -c" and ld

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I have the following source code in main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hi" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Using this command works, and creates the executable file:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp
```

But this commands don't work:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
ld -o main main.o
```

The second one errors with:

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000004000e8
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `std::cout'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
main.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `__dso_handle'
main.cpp:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `__cxa_atexit'
```

Comment: ld does not know about libstdc++

Comment: Don't call ld directly, unless you really need it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think if you use `ld` directly it does not include the C++ libraries by default. You can use `g++` to do the linking as well, it will call `ld` with the correct settings.

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -o main main.o
```

Answer (score 13):

GCC internally links against a few additional libraries and object files. To see what those are, execute `-###`, which will print the tool commands it would execute, including the linker. The linker command used by my GCC is (I made the actual `.o` file I invoked `g++` on **bold**, so you can spot it easily).

> /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0/collect2 --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 "--hash-style=both" -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0/../../../crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0/../../../crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0/../../.. **main1.o** "-lstdc++" -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.0/../../../crtn.o

You can substitute the `collect2` path by `ld` (if I remember correctly, `collect2` is only needed as a proxy for the real `ld` by GCC backends that don't support modern binary formats, to *collect* constructor and destructor functions according to their mangled name. The ELF format has native sections support for that).

Executing that command, with `ld` substituted literally, successfully links the executable.

Answer (score 8):

When you use `g++`, it also links the `libstd++` library which linker uses to resolve the names. But using `g++ -c` and then `ld` do not link the library automatically. You've to link the library manually now.

Try (untested):

```
ld -o main main.o -llibstd++
```

Or you can look into the correct syntax by reading this manual:

- [ld(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld)

Comment: the flag to link with libstdc++ library is -lstdc++

Answer (score 1):

Well, you didn't link in the standard library. `g++` does this for you automatically; that's why we use it: it wraps calls to `ccplus1` and `ld` with all the extras taken care of.

BTW, strictly speaking, the equivalent of `g++ main.cpp -o main` is:

```
cc1plus main.cpp -o main.o
ld -o main main.o
```

<sup>(`cc1plus` may well not be on your path; I found mine in `/usr/libexec/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.1/`)</sup>

`g++ -c main.cpp` does traditionally perform that first step. `g++ main.cpp -o main` wraps both.

`g++` is a *wrapper* to the individual compilation and linkage tools, tuned for C++. As such, it provides arguments to `cc1plus` and `ld` as it sees fit, including the argument to link in the C++ Standard Library:

```
ld -o main main.o -llibstd++
```

It'll also link in the runtime and possibly some other stuff.

In general, there is no need to try to do these things yourself: let `g++` take care of it.