# undefined reference to symbol 'socket@GLIBC_2.4' while linking

Tags: linux, linker, cross-compiling, glibc

I'm migrating from the default armhf cross compilation toolchain for ubuntu, to a precompiled toolchain from bootlin.com in order to have more control over the glibc version for a  project. Specifically, I'm using glibc 2.26 and gcc 6.4.0

However, I've been unable to succesfully link the project.
While linking, I get the error

```
/opt/glibc/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: ./src/foo.o: undefined reference to symbol 'socket@@GLIBC_2.4'
/opt/glibc/lib/gcc/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/lib/libc.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My compilation commands looks like this:

```
"/opt/glibc/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-g++" -std=c++03 \
-nostdinc -nostdinc++ \
"-I"/opt/glibc/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/6.4.0/"" \
"-I"/opt/glibc/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/6.4.0/"/arm-linux-gnueabihf" \
"-I"/opt/glibc/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/6.4.0/"/backward" \
"-I"/opt/glibc/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/6.4.0/"/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf" \
"-I"/opt/glibc/lib/gcc/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/6.4.0"/include" \
"-I"/opt/glibc/lib/gcc/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/6.4.0"/include-fixed" \
"-I"/opt/glibc/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot"/usr/include"" \
-I/opt/glibc/bin/../arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include/json-c -I/opt/glibc/bin/../arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include -I../3rdparty \
-O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/foo.d" -MT"src/foo.d" -o "src/foo.o" "../src/foo.cpp"
```

My linking command looks like this:

```
"/opt/glibc/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-g++" -v -o "out" \
-nostdlib -nostartfiles \
""/opt/glibc/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot"/usr/lib/crti.o" "/opt/glibc//lib/gcc/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/6.4.0"/crtbegin.o \
./src/foo.o ./src/bar.o \
-Wl,-Bstatic -L/opt/glibc/bin/../arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib -ljson-c \
-Wl,-Bdynamic "-L"/opt/glibc/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot"/lib" "-L"/opt/glibc/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot"/usr/lib" "-L/opt/glibc/lib" -lrt -pthread -L/opt/glibc/bin/../arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib -lbluetooth \
"/opt/glibc/lib/gcc/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/6.4.0"/crtend.o ""/opt/glibc/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot"/usr/lib/crtn.o"
```

I've been working on this for hours with no progress. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You link with `-nostdlib`.  This means that you have to link explicitly with the C library.  But your linker command mentions neither `-lc` nor `libc.so`.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I was missing a lot of libraries. I don't know why I thought they were handled automatically by the linker. I got it to link now :-)

I added the following extra flags `-lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc`

Just in case, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163208/how-to-link-c-object-files-with-ld helped me find out the missing flags.