# How can I make sure `iostream` is available to the linker?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, linker, iostream

I have the following C++ code in a file called `helloworld.cpp`:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
}
```

I would like to compile this manually so I can really understand how the compilation steps work with `gcc`, namely:

1. Preprocessing
2. Compilation
3. Assembly
4. Linking

This [article](https://earthly.dev/blog/g++-makefile/) gives some useful information about how to break up the compilation steps. And so I came up with the following:

1. Preprocessing
   `cpp helloworld.cpp > helloworld.i`
2. Compilation
   `g++ -S helloworld.i`
3. Assembly `as -o helloworld.o helloworld.s`
4. Linking
   `ld -o helloworld helloworld.o`

Everything seems to work except for the last step, as outlined by the article:

> `ld -o hello hello.o ...libraries...`
>
> The libraries argument above is a long list of libraries that you need to find out. I omitted the exact arguments because the list is really long and complicated, and depends on which libraries `g++` is using on your system. If you are interested to find out, you can run the command `g++ -Q -v -o hello hello.cpp` and take a look at the last line where `g++` invokes `collect2`

And so I tried running `g++ -Q -v -o helloworld helloworld.cpp`, but the result is extremely verbose.

I'm still unsure how to complete `ld` such that `iostream` can be available to the linker when I invoke it. How can I make sure `iostream` is available to the linker?

Comment: You usually don't need to specify standard libraries? The linker should get these automatically. Do you have some problems with that?

Comment: Like I said, this is for educational purposes.I'm aware that I can compile everything in one go without having to worry about specifying the standard libraries

Comment: Any consistent compiler installation would have standard libraries such as `iostream` available.

Comment: The output *is* very verbose, but as the article says, you only need to look at the last line, which invokes `collect2`. The `-L` options are library locations, and the `-l` options are actual libraries. The inputs named "*.o" are linked object files rather than libraries.

Comment: So which should I include in my `ld` invocation? The `-L` options or the `-l` options? Or both?

Comment: @user32882 both, they have completely different meanings.

Comment: Prefer to use `g++` to link rather than `ld`. But if you must use `ld`, [there are ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14163208/10077).

Comment: @FredLarson Is there a way to get `g++` to **only** link?

Comment: @user32882: Sure, just feed it only object and library files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments and posted answer I realized that the blog from which I was copying those commands makes things more complicated than they really need to be for my purposes. It's definitely possible to isolate every step of the compilation process using solely the `g++` command. Here's a Makefile I came up with:

```
all: preprocess compile assemble link

# helloworld.i contains preprocessed source code
preprocess:
    @echo "\nPREPROCESSING\n"; g++ -E -o helloworld.i helloworld.cpp

# compile preprocessed source code to assembly language. 
# hello.s will contain assembly code
compile:
    @echo "\nCOMPILATION\n"; g++ -S helloworld.i

# convert assembly to machine code
assemble:
    @echo "\nASSEMBLY\n"; g++ -c helloworld.s

# links object code with the library code to produce an executable
# libraries need to be specified here
link:
    @echo "\nLINKING\n"; g++ helloworld.o -o test

clean:
    @find -type f ! -name "*.cpp" ! -name "*.h" ! -name "Makefile" -delete
```

Now I can compile my C++ programs in such a way that I can track whether the preprocessor, compiler, assembler or linker is generating the error.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm still unsure how to complete ld such that iostream can be available to the linker when I invoke it.

You should *never* use `ld` to link any user-level programs, only when you are linking something esoteric, like an OS kernel or a boot loader.

Instead, (for user-level program) *always* use appropriate compiler driver (`g++` here).

While you *can* find out how the compiler driver eventually invokes `ld` internally (e.g. using `strace -fe execve -s 1024 g++ ...`), note that that command may change from version to version, and depends on a multitude of flags (`-pie` vs. `-no-pie`, `-shared`, `-static` etc.) and you chances of *continuing* to use correct `ld` command after a few months are nil.