# Use linker to build program but run executable shows 'No such file or directory'

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld, toolchain

I write a program including two files `main.c` and `comp.c`

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern int secure_func(int, int);
void main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
    int result = secure_func(1, 1);
}
```

**comp.c**

```
int secure_func(int text, int key)
{
    return text * key * key;
}
```

First, I directly use gcc to build program and run executable, that is fine.

> ```
> gcc -o main main.c comp.c
> ./main
> hello, world
> ```

Then I try to use toolchain to build program step by step like this

> ```
> gcc -c -o comp.o comp.c
> gcc -c -o main.o main.c
> ld -o main main.o comp.o -lc --entry main
> ```

ld generate a file `main`. But if I try to run it, it show error

> ```
> bash: ./main: No such file or directory
> ```

**The executable has X permission.**

**List Info**

```
>    ~/test/segtest2$ ls -l
>    total 24
>    -rw-rw-r-- 1 kail kail   88 Sep 28 21:20 comp.c
>    -rw-rw-r-- 1 kail kail   37 Sep 28 21:20 comp.h
>    -rw-rw-r-- 1 kail kail 1248 Sep 28 21:22 comp.o
>    -rwxrwxr-x 1 kail kail 3241 Sep 28 21:22 main
>    -rwxrwxr-- 1 kail kail  137 Sep 28 21:20 main.c
>    -rw-rw-r-- 1 kail kail 1568 Sep 28 21:21 main.o
```

Do I lost anything? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: could you show an "ls -l" of your current directory?

Comment: are you sure the file has execution rights? (more specifically, do you have the rights to execute the file?)

Comment: @Snappawapa - you would not get that error if there were no execute permissions.

Comment: @rghome can't hurt to check

Comment: You can use `gcc -v` to find out what commands gcc invokes to compile your program.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? Could you post the output of `strace ./main`?

Comment: @Snappawapa -  `echo "main(){}">t.c;cc t.c;chmod -x a.out;./a.out;` gives `-bash: ./a.out: Permission denied`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see how gcc works in verbose mode.

```
gcc -v -o main main.o comp.o
```

gcc links objects using following command

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/collect2 --build-id --eh-frame-hdr
>   -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=both -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o main -z relro
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crt1.o
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crti.o
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/crtbegin.o
>   -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../.. main.o comp.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc
>   --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/crtend.o
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crtn.o

If you replace /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/collect2 with **ld** then the linking process completes successfully.

> ld --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=both
>   -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o main -z relro /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crt1.o
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crti.o
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/crtbegin.o
>   -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../.. main.o comp.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc
>   --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/crtend.o
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crtn.o

[Refer this answer for further information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704780/using-only-g-works-but-not-g-c-and-ld)

Comment: could i get the intermediate linker script if i use gcc to build program ?

Comment: As like ld, gcc also supports linker script options with -T.

Comment: My meaning is if i use gcc or ld to build program without -T option, I guess gcc will generate default link script to deal with object files. Could I get this generated script?

Comment: If you do not specify -T option gcc or ld uses internal linker scripts. You can get linker script if you execute above commands with **--verbose** option.

Comment: thank you. it works. i get script by gcc -Wl,--verbose

Answer (score 2):

The argument `--entry=main` you pass to `ld` is not doing what you think it does. The entry point of a program is where the program starts. This is not `main` though, it's a function called `_start` defined in an object file `crt0.o` found somewhere on your system. To manually link a C program, invoke `ld` like this:

```
ld -o main main.o comp.o /path/to/crt0.o -lc
```

Do not supply `--entry` unless you know what it does.

Comment: What should I do if I want to fully control the steps of building? Could I define the path of `crt0.o` or define `_start` by myself? I use `gcc -v` to see the log of building. But no `ld` in output.

Comment: @KyL The object file `crt0.o` is part of the **C** **r**untime **e**nvironment. If you want to use the libc, your program should start up from that file, otherwise various things might not work (e.g. `malloc` or `stdio`) as the corresponding initialization is not being performed. The code in `crt0.o` basically sets up a stack, counts the arguments to your program, then calls into the libc to initialize it, then calls `main` and finally `exit`. You can skip it, but then you need to manually set up all of this stuff.

Comment: @KyL you can manually supply that path, but after looking again, I think that there are even more object files linked into the final binary by the C compiler. I do not recommend you to manually do this unless you work completely without the libc (manually writing startup code, too), as the exact steps the C compiler takes to link your binary are not stable and may change without notice.

Answer (score 1):

I see something similar when I try to run:

```
-bash: ./main: /lib/ld64.so.1: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

So you're probably not calling `ld` correctly.  Rather than using `ld`, use `gcc` instead to invoke it, as it takes care of details you'd otherwise have to worry about with `ld`.

```
gcc -c -o comp.o comp.c
gcc -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -o main main.o comp.o
```

Comment: For some purpose, I have to build executable step by step.

Comment: @KyL  You're still doing that.  Just using a different tool.

Comment: If I miss some options of ld, I have to know which options I miss. It is key point for my current work.