# Can't link a dynamic lib including iostream

Tags: c++, linker, g++, ld

`ld` is acting weirdly and I want to understand what's going on. In a `mycode.cpp`, I have the following:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include "mycode.hpp"

// awesome stuff here
```

I compile it with `g++ -fPIC -c mycode.cpp` and link it with `ld -Bshareable -o libmylib.so mycode.o`. Works like a charm.

Then I want to call `cout` in `mycode.cpp`. Actually, even before adding this `cout`, if I just add `#include <iostream>` in the code above, while linking I get the error

```
mycode.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
mycode.cpp:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `__dso_handle'
ld: mycode.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined hidden symbol `__dso_handle' can not be used when making a shared object
ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

If I link it with `g++ -shared`, it works, but that's not the point. I do not understand what's wrong here, and I am looking for insights.

EDIT: I understand one must call `g++` instead of `ld` directly. My problem is, I want to understand what's under the hood: why including iostream break things while algorithm is already here (so `ld` knows stdc++)

Comment: pretty sure your answer is right there: [Using only g++ works, but not “g++ -c” and ld](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704780/using-only-g-works-but-not-g-c-and-ld)

Comment: See http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/fyi-shared-libs-and-iostream-c-331113/page2.html#post2936978 but take into account that it is for a very old version of gcc

Comment: Don't call ld directly. Link with GCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> link it with `ld -Bshareable -o libmylib.so mycode.o`. Works like a charm.

It only works *by accident*.

User-level code should *never* be linked directly with `ld`, and should *always* use the appropriate compiler driver (`g++` here) to perform the link. Anything else, and you'll fail with weird link-time or runtime errors (just as you did here).